# Is $\mathbb{R}^2$ a convex set without extreme points?

Tags: vector-spaces, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, examples-counterexamples

My reasoning is, the vector space being a 'flat plane', a straight line joining any two points on it will always be contained in $\mathbb{R}^2$. And it has no points in it which cannot be on the straight line connecting two other points in the set (since the plane is infinite)

I am new to convex analysis and optimization techniques, so my line of thinking is very informal. Please let me know whether or not my approach is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any point $E \in \mathbb{R}^2$, because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, there exist two points (vectors) $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and an $\alpha \in (0,1)$ such that $E = \alpha x + (1-\alpha)y \in \mathbb{R}^2$.  Thus, the space does not contain any extreme points.

Comment: Nice one. My intuition was valid, then?

Comment: This doesn't seem to agree with the [definition of extreme point in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point). What is your definition of an extreme point?

Comment: @TonyK, you are right.  I edited my answer.

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas, I think your intuition about $\mathbb{R}^2$ being infinite is correct.  But, there are of course flat planes that do have extreme points.

Comment: @D.B. a non complicated example?

Comment: For a simple example, the space $\{y \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y \geq x^2 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas: For another simple example, $$\bigl\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x\ge0\textrm{ and }y\ge 0\bigr\}.$$

Comment: Is there an example where it is flat, unbounded everywhere and still containing an extreme point? (By being unbounded everywhere, I guess the possibility is instantly eliminated).

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas, perhaps the exterior of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that it is convex. Taking any $\vec x,\vec y\in\Bbb R^2,$ we have for all $\alpha\in(0,1)$ that $\alpha\vec x,(1-\alpha)\vec y\in\Bbb R^2$ by closure under scalar multiplication, and so $\alpha\vec x+(1-\alpha)\vec y\in\Bbb R^2$ by closure under addition.

As for extreme points, note that if $\vec x\ne\vec 0,$ then $\vec x$ lies on the open line segment between $\frac12\vec x$ and $\frac32\vec x,$ so cannot be extreme. I will leave it to you to show (by example) that $\vec 0$ cannot be an extreme point, either.

Comment: Or to avoid special cases, you can say that $\vec x$ lies on the open line segment between $\vec x-(0,1)$ and $\vec x+(0,1)$.

Comment: Origin lies on the line joining $(-0.4,-0.4)$ and $(0.4,0.4)$?

Comment: True story, @TonyK!

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas: Yes, indeed!

Comment: @Cameron: I don't understand your comment, I'm afraid. Are you just saying that my observation is correct?

Comment: @TonyK: Yes, that's what I was saying.

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas: In fact, your observation gives you a nice way to proceed without special cases, as TonyK points out. You need only show that $\vec x$ lies on the open segment joining $\vec x+(-0.4,-0.4)$ and $\vec x+(0.4,0.4).$ Or, more generally, taking any vector $\vec y\ne\vec 0,$ $\vec x$ lies on the open segment connecting $\vec x+(-1)\vec y$ and $\vec x+\vec y.$

Comment: I am getting it bit by bit. Thank you!